# No module named 'mlxtend'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am unable to install the mlextend package in Jupyter Python3 notebook

I have tried pip install mlxtend or pip3 install mlxtend, but either it shows syntax error for some reason on Python2 or it tells to try on the command line in python3. I have tried installing it on command line but it shows "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlextend (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlextend"

```
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules


ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-3-73c97be96c5f> in <module>()
----> 1 from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
      2 from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlxtend'`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the following command:

```
pip install mlxtend
```

You are currently trying to install `mlextend` (which does not exist) instead of `mlxtend`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the question. But I tried pip or pip3 install mlxtend. Its not happening. Sorry i'm a beginner so this question might be silly :p

Comment: I just ran the command, it works fine for me:
`Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 joblib-0.13.2 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-3.1.1 mlxtend-0.16.0 numpy-1.16.4 pandas-0.24.2 pyparsing-2.4.0 scikit-learn-0.21.2 scipy-1.3.0`

Comment: This solution worked for me as well in the Anaconda Prompt. Thank you, @Nordle!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue recently. What worked was importing the module first, and then getting the components:

```
import mlxtend
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above possible solutions. Under Anaconda/Miniconda environments it is also possible to use conda. Among the various options under https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mlxtend the following worked for me

conda install -c conda-forge mlxtend

Answer (score 0):

'pip install' works on Python2,if you install for Python3, use
`pip3 install mlxtend` instead

Comment: `File "<ipython-input-5-2ddfbd4be129>", line 1
        pip3 install mlxtend
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax `

Comment: @JayeshKumar !pip3 install mlxtend, you need ! at start when linux command in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Use `!pip install mlxtend`. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter difficulties with importing, follow these steps for resolving the issue:

1. **Install the package:**

   ```bash
   !pip install mlxtend
   ```
2. **Upgrade the package without dependencies:**

   ```bash
   pip install mlxtend --upgrade --no-deps
   ```
3. **Restart the kernel:**

   After completing the installation and upgrade, restart the kernel and attempt to import mlxtend again. This should address any import-related challenges you may be facing.

Comment: Please use backticks to distinguish code from English. Surround code that is to appear `inline` with single backticks. When you want a code block to appear separate from text, begin and end with lines that include three backticks. You can also append the name of the language to the first line with three backticks to get language-specific code formatting. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score -1):

```
#Import the libraries
#To install mlxtend run : pip install mlxtend

import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules,apriori
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about `pip install` not working.